# Root Motion animation clipping through Rigidbody objects? (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity, animation, rigidbody

I am trying to program a climbing system. Player has rigidbody, ledge has rigidbody. Both also have Colliders, and the Player animator is set to use Root Motion.

When Player grabs ledge and climbs up from it, the "climbing up" animation clips through the ledge. I'm not sure how to stop this- I thought that Rigidbody+Colliders on both GameObjects (player and ledge) would prevent clipping behavior but I guess not.

Any ideas how to approach fixing this issue? Thanks.